# gsed: Find, increment, and replace recursively

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

So I have a bunch of files scattered and deeply nested in a directory and I will like to find, increment by 2, and replace the number in every occurrence of a string e.g `fontSize: 10`.

For example:

`fontSize: 10` becomes `fontSize: 12`

and `fontSize: 30` becomes `fontSize: 32`,

I have tried `gsed -r 's/(.*)(\?fontSize=)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' file.kt` but it doesn't seem to work even for single files and moreover I want it to run on multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to do math, `sed`, `ed` and friends won't work. Something like:

```
find dir/ -name "*.kt" -exec perl -pi -e 's/fontSize: \K(\d+)/$1 + 2/eg' '{}' +
```

should do it.